# How Linq infers types from Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, delegates, lambda, extension-methods

Here is the original Linq:

```
       var developersUsingCSharp =
                from d in developers
                    where d.Language == "C#"
                    select d.Name;
```

This can be written as:

```
     Func<Developer, bool> filteringPredicate = d => d.Language == "C#";
     Func<Developer, string> selectionPredicate = d => d.Name;
     IEnumerable<string> developersUsingCSharp =
                    developers
                         .Where(filteringPredicate)
                         .Select(selectionPredicate);
```

Above we have explicitly defined the Func <T,T> delegates. So in

```
     Func<Developer, bool> filteringPredicate = d => d.Language == "C#";
```

it is known that d is of Developer type and return type is bool. Similarly, for

```
     Func<Developer, string> selectionPredicate = d => d.Name;
```

it is know that d is of Developer type and the return type is string. However in following valid form of the same query how are these types inferred:

```
IEnumerable<string> developersUsingCSharp =
                      developers
                         .Where(d => d.Language == "C#")
                         .Select(d => d.Name);
```

Comment: Referring to your last code block, that query is not yet inferred. It is still deferred by default unless you call the greedy methods like ToList(), ToArray().

Comment: @LeoLuis: He means type inference rather than fetching the data. These notions are not related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler knows that the elements in `developers` are `Developer`s, so it can infer the first type argument of both lambdas.  The compiler can infer the second type arguments by examining the return values of the lambdas: `bool` for the `Where`, and `string` for the `Select`.

Comment: So it does that at runtime?!?. Can it "examine" the types at runtime? Sure? Is it type safe then?

Comment: No, the compiler does it.  It is done at compile time.  It is type safe.

Comment: It does infering in compile time. So it absolutely type safe

Comment: Thanks no book specifies that explicitly, though they explain the code.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler knows `developers` implements `IEnumerable<Developer>`. This implies that any `IEnumerabler<T>` extensions off of `developers` will have items of type `Developer`.

Comment: ok so type of d can be inferred, but then what of return types? bool and string?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see a question there; but, have a look at section 7.5.2 of the C# spec.  I contains subsections that describe how anonymous and generic method resolution and type inference is performed.